Solving a functional equation and then limit
Question
Given $f : \mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function satisfying the functional equation :
$$ f(x+y) - 3^y f(x) = 3^x f(y)$$ for all $x,y$ $\in \mathbb{R}$.
Let $$L = \lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} + \frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)}+\cdots+ \frac{f^{n-1}(x)}{f^n(x)}\right)$$
Find L
My approach:
I could not find $f(x)$ itself. Usually, my approach is partially differentiating and setting one variable to zero, but it does not work in this case.
$$f'(x+y) - 3^y f(x) =(\ln3) 3^x f(y) $$
Setting $y=0$ simply gives $0=0$.
Any hints would help a lot. Thank you

What is $f'(x)$?  You are only assuming that $f(x)$ is continuous.  Did you mean to assume it was $C^{\infty}$?  Smooth?  Analytic?  Or are you claiming that those properties follow from the functional equation?

Do you have initial conditions for $f(x)$?  The constant function $f(x)=0$ satisfies the functional equation, but $L$ is undefined for that example.

@lulu I don't know, I guess it's not a zero function, as limit exists. And I don't know some terms as I'm in high school, could you elaborate?

All I am saying is that you need more assumptions before you can even start work on the question.  I don't think it's appropriate for us to try to guess at the intended assumptions.

I suggest:  search for another solution, or try to prove that $0$ is the only solution.

I edited the question, it had an error I'm so sorry @lulu

Also, pretty sure, f(x) is not equal to ero, as it was an mcq question

For a start.
If $f$ is continuous then so is $g(x) = f(x)/3^x$ and we have $$g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$$ so  , since $g$ is continuous $g(x)= ax$ for some real $a$. Then $f(x) = ax3^x$ and now it should be easy?
